# Why does space appear at the top of listview?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

recently i have making app and found problem on listview,

i want locationed container on the bottom and in it have listview.

and a space will appear on the top of the listview

i don't want space on the top of listview

how can i remove the space??

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:run_flutter/controller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TestController testController = TestController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: Get.width,
        height: Get.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                height: 50,
                width: Get.width,
                color: Colors.amber,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Text("data"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The 'bottom: 0' code cause your result.

Comment: This is to fix the yellow container at the bottom.

Comment: I have a listview inside the container,

Comment: I am sorry I confused...^^;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is written at official ListView class specification.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#external-links:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20ListView%20will%20automatically%20pad,link

*By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero padding property.*

Try to like this.

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs,

> By default, [`ListView`] will automatically pad the list's scrollable
> extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by [`MediaQuery`]'s
> padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero [`padding`]
> property.

You've to add MediaQuery with removePadding constructor (with removeTop to true) parent to remove the intentional extra top margin.

Here's code snippet:

```
 MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: ListView.builder(
     .......
   )
 );
```

For more information, follow [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14842).